# cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ea:header'. One of '{"http://ea.efa.com":header}' is expected

Tags: xml, xsd

I have been working on validation of a xml schema with an xsd file.After running the xml validation class, I have `cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ea:header'. One of '{"http://ea.efa.com":header}' is expected.` error on the console.

This the xsd file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xerces="http://xerces.apache.org"
        xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
        xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" 
        xmlns:ea ="http://ea.efa.com" targetNamespace="http://ea.efa.com
        xmlns:xades141="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#" elementFormDefault="qualified"
        attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
        <xs:import namespace="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" schemaLocation="XAdES.xsd"/>
        <xs:import namespace="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#" schemaLocation="XAdESv141.xsd"/>
        <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
            schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
        <xs:element name="ear">
            <xs:annotation>
               <xs:documentation>ear info</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="header" type="ear:headerType" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
```

this is the class that I use for xml creation:

```
    package com.meta.ea.adapter;

 //imports


public class XmlCreator {
    private static final Object NEW_LINE = "\r\n";
    private static final Object TAB = "\t";
    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(XmlCreator.class);
    ReportEngine engine ;

    public Connection conn;

    public XmlCreator(MetaFileWriter writer){
        this.engine = writer.processor.engine;
    }

    private CustomerType getCustomerType(String vknTckn){
        if (vknTckn.trim().length()==10) {
            return CustomerType.COMPANY;
        }else if(vknTckn.trim().length()==11) {
            return CustomerType.PERSON;
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private String getFromDB(Map row, String columnName){
        return (row.get(columnName) == null) ? "" : row.get(columnName).toString();
    }

    private ResultSet getTaxResultFromDB(int invoiceId) {
        ResultSet selectTaxesResult = null;
        try{
            PreparedStatement selectTaxesStatement;
            String selectTaxesQuery=IQuery.selectTaxesQuery;
            conn = createConnection();
            selectTaxesStatement = conn.prepareStatement(selectTaxesQuery, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY, ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);
            selectTaxesStatement.setInt(1, invoiceId);
            selectTaxesStatement.setFetchSize(ReportEngine.FETCH_SIZE_100);
            selectTaxesResult = selectTaxesStatement.executeQuery();
        }catch (SQLException ex) {
            logger.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return selectTaxesResult;

    }

    private Connection createConnection() throws Exception {
        Connection connect = null;
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/datasource-definition-beans.xml");
        Object o = ctx.getBean("dataSource");
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) o;
        connect = dataSource.getConnection();
        connect.setAutoCommit(false);
        return connect;
    }

    public String getEmptySignature(){
        //some stuff..
    }

    public String getUniqueId() throws EngineSystemException{
        return engine.getUniqueueID();
    }

    public String getHeaderContent() throws EngineSystemException{
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("<ear xmlns:ea=\"http://www.efa.com/ea.html\" xmlns=\"http://ea.efa.com\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"  xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://ea.efa.com ea.xsd\" xmlns:xades=\"http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#\">").append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append("<ear>");
        sb.append("<ea:header>").append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append(getContent("VERSION", engine.getVersion())).append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append("<ea:muk>").append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append(TAB).append(getContent("MUK_VKN", engine.company.getVknTckn())).append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append("</ea:muk>").append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append("<ea:preparer>").append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append(TAB).append(getContent("PREPARER_VKN", engine.getIntegratorVKN())).append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append("</ea:preparer>").append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append(getContent("REPORT_NO", engine.reportMasterDTO.getUuid())).append(NEW_LINE);
        String startOfPeriod= FormatterUtil.getFirstDayOfMountFromPeriod(engine.period).toString();
        String endOfPeriod= FormatterUtil.getLastDayOfMountFromPeriod(engine.period).toString();
        sb.append(TAB).append(getContent("PERIOD_START_DATE", startOfPeriod)).append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append(getContent("PERIOD_END_DATE", endOfPeriod)).append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append(getContent("PART_START_DATE", DateUtil.formatDate(engine.processor.fwReport.getPartStartDate(), DateUtil.DATE_FORMAT_2))).append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append(getContent("PART_END_DATE", DateUtil.formatDate(engine.processor.fwReport.getPartEndDate(), DateUtil.DATE_FORMAT_2))).append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append(getContent("PART_NO", String.valueOf(engine.processor.fileIndex))).append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append(getEmptySignature()).append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append("</ea:header>").append(NEW_LINE);

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private StringBuilder getContent(String property, String... values) {
        //some stuff
    }

    public  XmlBuilder newEntryDetail(Map<String, Object> faturaRow) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("<ea:fa>").append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(getInvoiceBody(faRow));
        sb.append(getTaxXml(faRow));
        sb.append(getCustomerInformation(faRow));
        sb.append(getInternetSaleInformation(faRow));
        sb.append("</ea:fa>").append(NEW_LINE);

        XmlBuilder xmlBuilder = new XmlBuilder(null);
        xmlBuilder.append(sb);
        return xmlBuilder;
    }

    //Some stuff..

    public String getFooterContent(){
        return "</ear>";
    }
}
```

And this is the the xml file that the above class creates:

```
 <ear xmlns:ea="http://www.efa.com/ea.html"
    xmlns="http://ea.efa.com"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
xsi:schemaLocation="http://ea.efa.com ea.xsd" xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#">
        <ear><ea:header>
            <ea:version>2.0</ea:version>
            <ea:muk>
                <ea:vkn>0510037140</ea:vkn>
            </ea:muk>
            <ea:preparer>
                <ea:vkn>6190524774</ea:vkn>
            </ea:preparer>
            <ea:reportNo>7BF70141-553A-40EE-896B-52D8F9E74765</ea:reportNo>
            <ea:periodStartDate>2015-06-01</ea:periodStartDate>
            <ea:periodEndDate>2015-06-30</ea:periodEndDate>
            <ea:partStartDate>2015-06-16</ea:periodStartDate>
            <ea:partEndDate>2015-06-16</ea:partEndDate>
            <ea:partNo>18</ea:partNo>
                <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="Signature_1">
                <ds:SignedInfo Id="SignedInfo_1">
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod
                        Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments" />
                    <ds:SignatureMethod
                        Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
                    <ds:Reference URI="">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform
                                Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                        <ds:DigestValue></ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>

                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue Id="id1">
                </ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo><ds:KeyValue><ds:RSAKeyValue><ds:Modulus/><ds:Exponent/></ds:RSAKeyValue></ds:KeyValue>     <ds:X509Data><ds:X509SubjectName>dummy</ds:X509SubjectName><ds:X509Certificate/></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo>     <ds:Object><xades:QualifyingProperties Target="Signature_1"><xades:SignedProperties Id="SignedProperties_1"><xades:SignedSignatureProperties><xades:SigningTime>2013-01-28T12:04:41+02:00</xades:SigningTime><xades:SigningCertificate><xades:Cert><xades:CertDigest><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><ds:DigestValue>+VSgWjpP9XlNGk6EM7WYWzHXQ2xrzUZLas1QR+IS7Rc=</ds:DigestValue></xades:CertDigest><xades:IssuerSerial><ds:X509SerialNumber>586340106507</ds:X509SerialNumber></xades:IssuerSerial></xades:Cert></xades:SigningCertificate><xades:SignerRole><xades:ClaimedRoles><xades:ClaimedRole></xades:ClaimedRole></xades:ClaimedRoles></xades:SignerRole></xades:SignedSignatureProperties></xades:SignedProperties></xades:QualifyingProperties></ds:Object>        
            </ds:Signature>
        </ea:header>
            //Some stuff..
        </ear>
```

I don't have so much experience on xml&xsd validation; so I couldn't see the mistake I made.How should I fix my code?

Comment: We need to see the section in the schema you commented out with `//Some stuff`, also note that your sample as posted is not even well-formed. Consider to post minimal but complete samples demonstrating the problem, so that we can reproduce the error. The most likely error is simply that you want the elements to be in the same namespace but you have defined a default namespace `xmlns="http://ea.efa.com"` but then a different one `xmlns:ea="http://www.efa.com/ea.html"` so that way the `ea:header` is in the wrong namespace. But I am guessing, we need to see the schema.

Comment: sorry for the confusion.I corrected the schema.Is your guess still valid as a solution the problem?

Comment: Please take more care to present your samples, I can't tell what the target namespace is as `targetNamespace="http://ea.efa.com` is not complete, I can't tell what `<xs:element name="header" type="ear:headerType" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>` refers to as neither `ear` nor `headerType` is defined. And why does the input sample have two nested `ear` elements?

Answer (score 0):

take this definition:

```
<xs:element name="header" type="ear:headerType" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
```

in your schema, I don't find a namespace with the prefix `ear`